# How to fill matrix with mapply R function?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply

I am trying to use [apply](/questions/tagged/apply) function in [r](/questions/tagged/r) instead of [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) to fill a [matrix](/questions/tagged/matrix) with two empty columns:

```
  cellName genesNum genesSum oneUMI
1       c1       NA     1917     NA
2       c2       NA     7143     NA
3       c3       NA     2063     NA
4       c4       NA     1733     NA
5       c5       NA     1876     NA
6       c6       NA     1800     NA
```

So I rewrote this :

```
    for(i in 1:ncol(countMatrix)){
        vec <- countMatrix[,i]
        coldata$genesNum[coldata$cellName == colnames(countMatrix)[i]] <- length(vec[vec > 0])
        coldata$oneUMI[coldata$cellName == colnames(countMatrix)[i]] <- length(vec[vec == 1])
    }
```

to this :

```
fillColData <- function(nameColumn){
    vec <- countMatrix[, nameColumn]
    coldata$genesNum[coldata$cellName ==  nameColumn] <- length(vec[vec > 0])
    coldata$oneUMI[coldata$cellName == nameColumn] <- length(vec[vec == 1])
}
```

and I use `as.matrix(mapply(fillColData, colnames(countMatrix)))`. But instead to have full filled matrix like that :

```
  cellName genesNum genesSum oneUMI
1       c1      934     1917    674
2       c2     2346     7143   1407
3       c3     1046     2063    747
4       c4      904     1733    628
5       c5      939     1876    673
6       c6      981     1800    719
```

I just have the last column  :

```
    [,1]
c1  674
c2 1407
c3  747
c4  628
c5  673
c6  719
```

I don't understand why, because iteratively it's correct. Can someone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: The usual approach would be to join/merge data frames if the new values come from a separate data frame, or simply bind columns if the new values are a vector. See `join` functions and `bind_cols` from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: Please explain how you fill `genesNum` and `oneUMI` columns?

Comment: To fill genesNum, for each cells I get in the count matrix the number of genes with more than one read. And to fill the oneUMI, for each cells I get the number of genes with exactly one read. You can see the fillColData  function I used above.